# How can I dynamically update menu items in ncurses?

Tags: c++, ncurses, curses

Is there a standard way to add/remove items, or change the descriptions, etc ? Or do I need to simply unpost, free up everything, then reallocate a new menu and start over? My menu has up to 2000 options so I'd really like to avoid allocating and reallocating if possible.

There is this question that doesn't really have any answer:
[Creating a dynamic menu in ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974444/creating-a-dynamic-menu-in-ncurses)

Comment: i directly change item.description.str and change item.description.length. but this broke menu's width. seems ncurse directly use printw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - there's no standard way.  With ncurses, the structure members are visible, so you *could* make a variation of `new_item`, which modified the pointers (and lengths) for the text.

Aside from that, there's (standard) `set_menu_items`.  A quick read of the source shows that you *could* replace the items in the menu with the same list (with a different item here and there), but that resets the overall menu state, so you would have to save/restore those values before posting the menu again.

Comment: Thanks, digging into that struct I got it to work by replacing the underlying pointer. but it doesn't udpate the display until the cursor moves over the item. Is there  a way to force it to redraw? ( I tried refresh() but that didn't do it)

Comment: The easy way is to re-post the menu (via `set_menu_items`).  `refresh` only affects a window; menus contain several windows.

Comment: @ThomasDickey sorry for rewind this old post. i'm sharing confuse with jterm. but `set_menu_items` not work for me ( I wanna change item->name when key pressed). Re-post( `unpost_menu` then `post_menu`) do worked but that's kind of ugly